# array undefine after a setState and an API result

Tags: react-native, state, setstate

I am beggining with react-native.

I'm trying to create an ImageGallery.
One of the step to have this Gallery is to initiate an array in a state with the result of an API.

1. I initiate a void array on the state named "images"
2. I call the API --> by a console.log, i'm seeing the result correctly
3. I want to setState my array "images"
4. I want to read my array "images"

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Image,
    FlatList
} from 'react-native';

export default class TestGallery extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        images: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("*************************************")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .then((result) => {
                this.setState({
                    images: result.images
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    error
                });
            }
        )
}

render() {
    console.log('Step 3 : RENDER')

    console.log(this.state.images)

    return (
        <View style={{ height: 200, width: 200 }}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.images}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Image
                        style={{ height: 200, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
                        source={this.state.images}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </View>

    )
}
}
```

Console :

```
Step 3 : RENDER
Array []
Array [
  "photo(3).jpg",
  "photo(7).jpg",
  "photo(2).jpg",
  "photo(8).jpg",
  "photo(14).jpg",
  "photo(12).jpg",
  "photo(6).jpg",
  "photo(15).jpg",
  "photo(10).jpg",
  "photo(9).jpg",
  "photo(5).jpg",
  "photo(1).jpg",
  "photo(11).jpg",
  "photo(13).jpg",
  "photo(4).jpg",
]

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result.images')]
```

Does someone can help me ?
Why i can't setState my array "Images"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As you can see in your console.log, your response is already an array of images (names and not URLs as it seems). You are expecting an object with an `images` key. Well, you would have to adjust your API Endpoint for that. To put your result array into your state you could do the following.

```
fetch(...)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
  console.log(json)
  this.setState({images: json})
})
```

2. Your images will not show up with this code, since what you get is image names. When these images are saved within your RN project you would have to use `require` for the Image source with the correct path to the images. But I am pretty sure you want to render from `uri`, so you would have to use `uri` for the Image source with a correct URL to the image.
3. You need to use the `item` from your `renderItem` function for the Image source, since that would be one item of `this.state.images`. You pass the whole array saved in `this.state.images` to the Image source.

You really should read the documentation more carefully.
Image: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image
Flatlist: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html